# Отследить отключение интернета при запросах к сайту

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, requests, request

Есть скрипт, который в цикле делает запросы к какому-то сайту. Запрос может быть неуспешным (по разным причинам), поэтому тело цикла обёрнуто в `try...except`.

Как можно в блоке `except` определить событие "проблема на моей стороне" (например, перезагрузка роутера), чтобы можно было залогировать текущие результаты, чтобы не потерять работу скрипта?

Как вариант придумал ввести порог неуспешных реквестов. Например, если это 10ый неуспешный запрос подряд, то значит проблемы у меня, а не на сайте. Есть ли решение лучше?

Comment: А какая связь между неуспешными запросами и потерей работы скрипта?

Comment: `если это 10ый неуспешный запрос подряд, то значит проблемы у меня, а не на сайте.` ловить исключение при ошибке работы по сети и вести счетчик, если значение стало 10, то выходим из функции

Comment: @gil9red мне понятно, как реализовывать эту идею)

Comment: @CrazyElf скрипт накапливает информацию с запросов, но сохраняет её на диск только всю вместе, а не каждую итерацию цикла, поэтому сохранение либо после цикла, либо в блоке except. Сохранять каждую итерацию дорого, т.к. итераций много, и запись на диск дорого стоит

Comment: @name Ну в этих случаях вывод буферизуют. Например, ждут 100 итераций - и сохраняют что накопилось. Или в БД пишут, они заточены на то, чтобы в них писать хоть по одной записи.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, это решит проблему с потерей данных. Но если отключили интернет, то скрипт как минимум будет простаивать, а хотелось бы его завершить. То есть всё же надо отследить это событие

Comment: @name, например https://github.com/gil9red/wallpaper_from_himawari/blob/87f5af315c8fb01fd6d3f162f27990a16fcbd1c2/run_one.py#L71 следите за переменной `attempts`

Comment: @name Ну так то да, считать ошибки тут логично. Причём подряд.

Comment: никак это не сделать..........